# Extend Convert.ToString() to pad binary output

Tags: c#

I can use `Convert.ToString` to convert an integer to its binary representation:

```
int x = 10;
string value = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

I get `1100`.

It can even handle negative numbers, as I get `111...0110` (32 bits).

```
int x = -10;
string value = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

How can I extend this function so that I can give third parameter to get the result with bit filled with 0 (positive value) or 1 (negative value)?

For example, with `Convert.ToString(10, 2, 5)` --> `01100`, and `Convert.ToString(-10, 2, 5)` --> `10110`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write my own extension:

```
public static class ConvertEx
{
    public static string ToStringEx(this int input, int baseVal, int sign)
    {
       var result = sign.ToString();
       result += Convert.ToString(input, baseVal);
       return result;
    }
}
```

call it as :

```
(-10).ToStringEx(2,1)
```

Also there is no need to pass sign just for convention (with question) I pass it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't extend the `Convert.ToString` function as such, since it's `static`, but you can easily just use `.PadLeft`:

```
int x = 10;
string value = Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(5, '0');
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

And, of course, feel free to make that into your own function. But you can't put it inside `Convert`.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is an Extension Method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: extension methods don't work with static classes (they don't "add" a static method to a class)